# How to create temporary States in ReactRedux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've been using Redux for a month and when a project gets really large it doesn't seem necessary to expose the entire app to all the values of every Reducer. Is there a good way to create temporary States or create individual States for components?

Am I thinking of this all wrong or is it structured this way for a reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming by "values of every reducer" you are referring to the entire app state.

You can certainly slice up your state and expose only the necessary pieces to specific components.  That is what the `connect` method from the `react-redux` bindings is for.  `connect` takes a function (e.g. `mapStateToProps`) which in turn takes your entire app state and exposes only the pieces you designate as props to the component you are "connecting" to redux.

For example, suppose you have a simple React component like this that shows a user's name and address:

```
var myComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>{Name from redux state goes here}</div>
      <div>{Address from redux state goes here}</div>
    );
  }
});
```

Obviously you don't need to send your entire app state to this component, just the piece with the user's name and address.  So you use `connect` like so:

```
// the "state" param is your entire app state object.  
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    name: state.name,
    address: state.address
  }
}

var connectedComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(myComponent);
```

The wrapped `myComponent` now effectively looks like this:

```
var myComponent = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
   name: React.PropTypes.string // injected by connect
   address: React.PropTypes.string // injected by connect  
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.name}</div>
      <div>{this.props.address}</div>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Yep I'm doing this already. I'm trying to avoid having so many reducer files. If I only need to store 1 variable for a component it feels like overkill to create a reducer for this trivial variable that only gets used in a single place.

Comment: Yeah to deal with that issue, I reverted to just storing local, transient state in the components themselves and using `setState`.  Putting the entire app state, including trivial things like whether or not a flyout is open, into your reducers / store sounds great in theory, but I found things quickly got unwieldy.  I now just use the stores for state that needs to be shared across the app.

Comment: Yes, I think I will also start using `setState` for components that don't need to communicate with the rest of the app.

Comment: Yes, in my case there is a upload progress bar, I don't think it is necessary to put progress bar state into redux just stay in component state.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles):

> The state of your whole application is stored in an object tree within
>   a single store.

One state. One store. That's it. You can create local states in your individual components that are informed by the larger application state, but at that point you're just copying parts of the larger state that already exist.

Keep in mind that in a complex app, you will not make the entire state available to your "smart" components. Even if you have 100 reducer functions, when you [connect a component to the store](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react#implementing-container-components), you can use `mapStateToProps` to pick only the parts of the application state you want, and create props for your component from those. So you would never see all of the parts of the state that you don't use, even if you know in the back of your mind that they exist.

This is really a great architectural pattern. With one state you have a [single source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Source_of_Truth). It is impossible for any part of your app to have stale data because of this. Remember that you are only defining your state *structure* when you initialize your application state, and not loading all *data*. Therefore, there is no performance hit by initializing the whole structure at the start. And again, you will never be loading the entirety of your application state into a single component anyway (unless it requires that) so your props will always be manageable.

Comment: Yea I'm trying to avoid having so many reducer files. If I only need to store 1 variable it feels like overkill to create a reducer for this trivial variable that only gets used in a single place.

Comment: Well it depends on what the trivial variable is. If it's something like a flag or something else that's not truly data, then there's no harm in creating it as a local component state. At the end of the day, it's all just javascript so you can add whatever vars you want. There is no Redux police. However anytime you deal with actual *data* it makes the most sense to trickle down from an application state. It might feel like overkill for a small app, but trust me, this scales really well and ensures your data must always be fresh as it can only ever come from one place.

Comment: Haha yea there's no Redux police but getting suggestions on what people think is the proper way to do it is helpful. So I will probably just use `setState` in my components for this.